# Ignore formatting in Slack App when reading messages

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm building a Slack App which is only interested in actual user input in message, regardless if it's bold, italic, or a web link.

What would be the best way to remove all the formatting characters, such as `_`, `*`, etc, and leave actual text only?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is actually to ignore the *text* param entirely, as it is inherently lossy, and to instead parse what you want from the *blocks* param, which gives an exact representation of what the user saw in their slack client message field when they posted their message.

To demonstrate this, here's a simple example

| what you type | WYS | *text* | *blocks*[0]["elements"]["elements"] | parsing text from *blocks* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [a][space][*][b][*] | ​a **b** | a *b* | [{"type":"text","text":"a "}, {"type":"text","text":"b", "style":{"bold":true}}] | a b |
| [a][*][b][*][←][←][←][space] | a *b* | a *b* | [{"type":"text","text":"a *b*"}] | a *b* |

Unfortunately for now, the Slack API does not give you the *blocks* param in command events, only message events. Hopefully they will fix this, but until then you may wish to use regular messages instead of slash commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node.js there is a module for this:

https://openbase.io/js/remove-markdown/documentation

Note that this is for markdown and not Slack's variant ***mrkdwn*** so it might not work.

Comment: Thanks! I use Java, and there are many markdown libs available. But using them looks like a "hack", especially for the reason you mentioned (it's not exactly a markdown).

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get the unformatted message in python by looping through the array.

````
def semakitutu(message, say):
    user = message['user']
    # print(message)
    hasira = message['blocks']
    hasira2 = hasira[0]['elements'][0]['elements']
    urefu = len(hasira2)
    swali = ''
    for x in range(urefu):
        swali=swali+hasira2[x]['text']
    print(swali)
    say(f"Hello <@{user}>! I am running your request \n {swali}")```
````